# T-SQL Select a bunch of data from another DB and Copy to DB2

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

H all,

Fist of all, thanks for reading this.
My Question is, how can I select a bunch of data from ANOTHER database and insert to my own database with same coloum name and field?
I just can think of is using select from DB1 and then insert into DB2.
I plan to written this process inside a stored procedures. 
Is there a better way to do so?

Development enviroment :Sql server 2008 and VS2010(using .net C# to excecute Stored prod)
Thank you, Appreciate its lot. 
And Please don't hesitate to voice out my error or mistake.I wish to learn from mistake

LiangCk

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following if its the same database server

```
INSERT INTO [DB].[UserName].[TableName]
Select * from [DB2].[UserName].[TableName]
```

- [DB] is the name of database 1
- [DB2] is the name of database 2
- [UserName] is your sql server username (dbo,....)
- [TableName] is, off course, your table

If you have different sql servers you can connect both servers 
using linked server.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff772782.aspx

Comment: dknaack: is linked server will made the executing performance better?